# PHP - mysql connection timeout delay

Tags: php, mysql, iis, mysqli

We're testing a php connection to a mysql DB using the following syntax:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("10.0.0.6:3306", "wordpress-user", "Passw0rd", "wordpress");

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

The issue is that on success the response is immediate, however, on failure, the response is always 22 seconds. Would it be possible to reduce the 22 seconds to a quicker response on connection failure?

We've already reduced the mysql.connect_timeout to 5 seconds, however this had no effect as timeout / response was still 21 seconds. Any ideas please?

The PHP server is hosted on IIS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try it without the mysql port number?

Comment: @C0dekid no effect. Had tried it. Thanks though :)

Comment: if you are connecting to the local server simply use `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`. If you are connecting to a remote server, it can be a DNS issue.

Comment: @C0dekid it's a server on the same LAN but no localhost. I'm using the IP so DNS should not be an issue

Answer (score 0):

There is connection option, [MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.options.php):

```
$my = mysqli_init();
$my->options(MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 1);
$my->real_connect('non-existent-ip',"wordpress-user", "Passw0rd", "wordpress");
```

will make it 1 second timeout

Comment: Thanks that works, however I'm looking to implement this at server level rather than at php-script level. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the server files, you can edit `my.cnf` (MySQL configuration file), and change the lines `wait_timeout = 28800` and `interactive_timeout = 28800` to the values you want.

Otherwise you'd need to do it from the script itself.

Also, [check this link](https://www.pythian.com/blog/connection-timeout-parameters-mysql/), it may help you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I do have access to my.ini / my.cnf file, however I'm trying to achieve this from a PHP-server side and not from MYSQL server side. Reason being, if the MYSQL server is down, I would like the PHP server / script to return the timeout response promptly. Any ideas please?

Comment: [Check this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php). Also read the [notes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php#refsect1-function.set-time-limit-notes)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use persistent mysql connection if you run your code from php-fpm. This helped us with spontaneous mysqli:real_connect timeouts.